# Nestjs - Inject Data In Decorator

Tags: nestjs, decorator, inject

```
class CreateAssetDto{
  assetName: string;
  tenant: Tenant;
}

export const InjectTenant = createParamDecorator(
    (data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
      const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      let createAssetDto = new CreateAssetDto();
      createAssetDto.tenant = new Tenant("JAY")
      return createAssetDto;
    }

);

async create(@InjectTenant() createAssetDto: CreateAssetDto) {
    console.log(createAssetDto.tenant);
```

Hi, how to inject data using decorator parameter. for example everytime I call create function. it automatically inject tenant property.

when I tried it. it never call @InjectTenant decorator

Comment: using the `data` parameter? `@InjectTenant('foo')` then `data === 'foo'`

Answer (score 0):

You can Inject it in the request so that you can get the object wherever you want to... Take a look at the following code

```
export const InjectTenant = createParamDecorator(
(data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
  const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest(); 
  let createAssetDto = new CreateAssetDto();
  createAssetDto.assetName = "CAR"
  request.createAssetDto = createAssetDto;
  return request;
}
);
```

now in your controller, you can access it via `Req()` method

```
@InjectTenant()
@Post('/Your-Route')
async create(@Body() createAssetDto: CreateAssetDto, @Req() req:any ) {
console.log(req.createAssetDto);
}
```

Comment: what if I want to inject object createAssetDto. without using @req or new property

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way for doing that. Besides the official documentation makes use of this method. Using request will also help to access the object on other places as well. Hope it helps :)

Comment: the idea of injecting the datasource in the request is awesome